# Java EE with embedded database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cassandra, database, nosql

I have several applications/microservices running on different application servers. I want to persist some data in each of the applications for statistical/monitoring purposes. The data-format is very simple and there will probably only be a couple of tables in each database. The performance has to be very fast with minimal overhead.

All the applications are running on Java EE 6 servers. I'm therefore looking for a database that can be embedded on each application server with high performance and minimal configuration.

Requirements:

- Easy to embed on a Java EE application server
- High performance and minimal overhead/footprint
- Minimal configuration and maintenance
- NoSQL is preferable
- Clean Java API
- Possible to do SQL-like queries on each database and across the different databases
- Time-to-live on insert statements
- Free
- Preferable Open Source

Does anyone have experience with similar solutions or suggestions for technologies suitable for the use case?

Cassandra looks very interesting, but it's hard to find any documentation on how to embed it easily in a Java EE container.

Comment: The lack of documentation about embedding Cassandra is due to the fact that Cassandra is not really meant to be used as a small embedded database, but rather as a scalable, highly performant, always available database.

Answer (score 1):

H2 should satisfy nearly all of your needs (except for the NoSQL preference) http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like a usable alternative. Do you know if H2 has support for "time to live"/auto-delete on inserted rows? I know Cassandra supports this and this will make the maintainability easier.

Comment: Not that I know of (which doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't - my use of H2 is pretty minimal). You might want to take a look at Apache Derby, I've never used it myself but it may be more feature rich than H2 http://db.apache.org/derby/